# Passing Variable from Until Loop into If statement

Tags: bash, variables, unix

I have the following until script with an embedded `if` statement. The embedded `if` statement uses a `new_variable` as defined by the parameters of the `until` loop.
The `new_variable` is not passing into the command when I put the commands in the background, but the loop does work if I don't put the commands in background. How do I define a new variable in the `until`/`if` loop? Any tips would be most appreciated!

```
counter=1
stop=10

until [ $counter -gt $stop ]; do
    if [ ... ]

        (new_variable=$(awk 'NR=='$counter'{print $2}' file )
          command1;
          command2;
          command3) &

        let counter+=1

    fi
done
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I tried to make your code runnable by 1. adding the missing `then`, 2. Creating a file containing "foo bar1", "foo bar2" etc up to 10, 3. replacing `command1;` etc with `echo "$new_variable"`. When I ran it, it output `bar1` to `bar10` in an arbitrary order as expected. How can I reproduce your problem?

Comment: You know that background processes are executed in a separate environment and that any variables set in that environment aren't propagated back to the invoking environment, right?

Comment: If `new_variable` is (intended to be) used by `command1`, etc, it needs to be exported.